# Error retrieving a new session from the selenium server

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver, nightwatch.js

I'm attempting to setup Nightwatch.js for the first time. I'm following the following tutorial: https://github.com/dwyl/learn-nightwatch

Unfortunately I've hit a roadblock, and I'm in need of help resolving it.

> Error retrieving a new session from the selenium server. 
>    Connection refused! Is selenium server started?

[image]

**nightwatch.conf.js**

```
module.exports = {
  "src_folders": [
    "test"// Where you are storing your Nightwatch e2e/UAT tests
  ],
  "output_folder": "./reports", // reports (test outcome) output by nightwatch
  "selenium": { 
    "start_process": true, // tells nightwatch to start/stop the selenium process
    "server_path": "./node_modules/nightwatch/bin/selenium.jar",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 4444, // standard selenium port
    "cli_args": {  
      "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "./node_modules/nightwatch/bin/chromedriver"
    }
  },
  "test_settings": {
    "default": {
      "screenshots": {
        "enabled": true, // if you want to keep screenshots
        "path": './screenshots' // save screenshots here
      },
      "globals": {
        "waitForConditionTimeout": 5000 // sometimes internet is slow so wait.
      },
      "desiredCapabilities": { // use Chrome as the default browser for tests
        "browserName": "chrome"
      }
    },
    "chrome": {
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "javascriptEnabled": true // set to false to test progressive enhancement
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**guinea-pig.js**

```
module.exports = { // addapted from: https://git.io/vodU0
  'Guinea Pig Assert Title': function(browser) {
    browser
      .url('https://saucelabs.com/test/guinea-pig')
      .waitForElementVisible('body')
      .assert.title('I am a page title - Sauce Labs')
      .saveScreenshot('ginea-pig-test.png')
      .end();
  }
};
```

Based on the configuration setup. I kept it as basic as possible. I cannot pinpoint the source where it would suggest another selenium server has started. Any ideas?

**EDIT: TIMEOUT ERROR**

[image]

Comment: Your error related screenshots seem to be hinting at something around Chrome (or) maybe even the ChromeDriver . But since you haven't included the complete error contents properly its hard to say. I would suggest that you first take a look at the error a bit more closely (or) share the complete error contents in your question so that its easy to find out what happened.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan here is my question with the complete error contents, can you help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40454321/error-when-running-selenium-server-via-nightwatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution involved deleting my instance of Chrome (although it was the most recent version) and simply reinstalling the browser again.

I encourage all facing the same problems to first look at QualiT's response above as it's the more conventional troubleshooting strategy.

Answer (score 1):

In your nightwatch.json file, within "selenium"

Make sure your server path is correct.
Make sure your webdriver.chrome.driver path is correct.

Those are specific to your machine. If those do not refer to the correct file in the correct location, you'll get problems starting the selenium server.

After that, you want to make certain that the version of the selenium server you have works with the version of chrome driver you have and that that will work with the version of the Chrome browser you have.

But as [Krishnan Mahadevan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/679824/krishnan-mahadevan)indicated, without the whole error message, we can't be of much more help.

Comment: Thank you, they are in fact pointed in the right direction. The problem was that I needed the most recent version of the selenium standalone server. However, now when I attempt to run a test (guinea-pig.js), I consistently receive a time out error. I've tried even simple tests that just check for a page title, and they all fail...I included the most recent screenshot above, any idea why this is happening? The guinea-pig.js is designed to be a simple test to ensure it runs properly. No reason that should fail!

Comment: If you installed a new selenium server, you probably need to stop and re-start it. Two options here: restart your machine, go online and look up how to do it in the terminal. I've had to do that before when installing a new version, so that'd be my first guess.

Comment: Unfortunately same result, always receiving a timed out error :(

Comment: What version of chromeDriver? What version of Chrome?

Comment: Also, are you seeing chrome open and load the page?

Comment: It does open the chrome browser, but no content appears and it closes very fast. The url from guinea-pig.js that it should be opening is visible when navigating to it manually. I have the latest copy of chromedriver (2.25)

Comment: Again, I am not convinced you are pointing at the right version of ChromeDriver. Have you removed the old version from that drive/location?

Comment: Sorry, your setup there is mystifying to me. That's not how my Nightwatch install is setup. My configuration is contained in nightwatch.json. It's not clear to me what is going on with your install.

Comment: I followed the step by step instructions at https://github.com/dwyl/learn-nightwatch, if you have your own step by step guide that works, I would love to hear!

Comment: One more question, does the server you are testing, open HTML page, or does it open PDFs?

Comment: I fixed the issue. Turns out i had to delete and reinstall chrome. Even though I had the latest version, physically getting a new copy did the trick, thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad it worked out. You should post that answer in case someone else runs into the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had got the same issue when I used `vue-cli init` on my project. after I updated to Java 9, this problem was resolved.