# Error when running Selenium Server via Nightwatch

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js

I'm attempting to run a simple test script. But I receive the following error:

[image]

I have my nightwatch config file setup as so:

**nightwatch.conf.js**

```
module.exports = {
  "src_folders": [
    "tests"// Where you are storing your Nightwatch e2e/UAT tests
  ],
  "output_folder": "./reports", // reports (test outcome) output by nightwatch
  "selenium": { 
    "start_process": true, // tells nightwatch to start/stop the selenium process
    "server_path": "./node_modules/selenium-standalone/.selenium/selenium-server/2.53.1-server.jar",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 4444, // standard selenium port
    "cli_args": {       "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "./node_modules/selenium-standalone/.selenium/chromedriver/2.25-x64-chromedriver"
    }
  },
  "test_settings": {
    "default": {
      "screenshots": {
        "enabled": true, // if you want to keep screenshots
        "path": './screenshots' // save screenshots here
      },
      "globals": {
        "waitForConditionTimeout": 5000 // sometimes internet is slow so wait.
      },
      "desiredCapabilities": { // use Chrome as the default browser for tests
        "browserName": "chrome"
      }
    },
    "chrome": {
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "javascriptEnabled": true // set to false to test progressive enhancement
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**guinea-pig.js**

```
module.exports = { // addapted from: https://git.io/vodU0
  'Guinea Pig Assert Title': function(browser) {
    browser
      .url('https://saucelabs.com/test/guinea-pig')
      .waitForElementVisible('body')
      .assert.title('I am a page title - Sauce Labs')
      .saveScreenshot('ginea-pig-test.png')
      .end();
  }
};
```

The server path and chromedriver path are accurate and the most recent copy. I also have the latest version of chrome installed. Can someone please help me understand what could be the problem? Thanks!

**Edit:** I've also restarted the whole computer, same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the latest version of the Selenium standalone server `v.3.0.1`

If that doesn't work, then you can upgrade your chromedriver to the latest version and test. You can find the different versions here:

https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

Also make sure you are using the most recent version of Nightwatch `v0.9.9` and update it in you package.json file.

Answer (score 0):

It is written very clear , your chrome version is lower than what chromedriver needs, just update your chrome to the latest version